# Angular-ngRoute: force ng-view contents, allow navigation afterwards

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

While using ngRoute, I want to have Angular configured so that the current contents of ng-view are left as the contents for the current route, and allow the user to navigate away to different routes, rendering their respective templates afterwards:

#### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z4qGEh7u8OsbnYUv2MeS?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
</ul>

<div ng-view>
  <ul>
    <li>Some</li>
    <li>Soon obliterated</li>
    <li>Content</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  })
  .when('/view2', {
    templateUrl: 'view2.html',
    controller: 'View2Ctrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/view1'
  })
})
.controller('View1Ctrl', function() {

})
.controller('View2Ctrl', function() {

});
```

---

***When the user first sees the page, I want him to see the following:***

[image: First load]

*Note: Angular needs to be bootstrapped at this point, with directives functioning in this area*.

*Note 2: This content should be in the actual HTML of the page, not in a template or script tag.*

---

***Then, when the 'view2' link is clicked:***

[image: Clicks on 'view2']

---

***And then, when the 'view1' link is clicked:***

[image: Clicks on 'view1']

---

My first thought was using `$route.updateParams(newParams)` but I think that's not really its purpose.

**EDIT**
I ended up using

```
//Server-side rendered code

myModule
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('<# my current route #>',
        {
            templateUrl: '/server-static',
        });

 angular.bootstrap(myModule);
```

In app.js:

```
 myModule
    .config('$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/my-client-routes',
            {
                templateUrl: '/my-template.html',
            }); // etc.
```

How can I *trick* Angular into thinking that the contents of `ng-view` are the appropiate contents for the current entry route? Can I just *cancel* route resolution/ngView directive (or make it transclude) rendering for first load? Or if not possible, what's the preferred method to do this?

Thanks

**EDIT:** See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20620699/890899) that proposes adding the contents of ng-view to `$templateCache` through a custom directive.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for `templateUrl` to be a function. In which case you can actually change the view based on some kind of state:

```
var initialized = false;

$routeProvider
.when('/view1', {
 templateUrl: function(){
   if(initialized){ 
     return 'view1.html';
   }

   initialized = true;

   return 'view-initial.html';
 },
 controller: 'View1Ctrl'
})
```

Here is a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8OfFMrncLmkJDMz5XYWU?p=preview) based on yours.

Comment: Could you think of any way to have the contents of view-initial.html inside the actual ng-view directive like it's shown in the question HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The task you're asking help for can be achieved in a number of ways. @Josh offers a good one. Using $templateCache is another option. But, as you correctly said, these are tricks.

Correct and only recommended approach is to use dedicated template for a default route. You can specify it via external file, via template cache or even script tag, but it's much better, clear and easy to support.

If it's your own code - just choose any preferred way you like. If you want it to be shared with community, used as open-source or enterprise solution - I'd suggest to use the only recommended approach.

Or... look into [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/) )) . May be it's nested views support is the option you need.

Comment: I had someone else recomment ui.router for this. However, while looking at it's documentation, it seems like the uiView directive is effectively wiped out the same as ngView. Perhaps you could provide a link to a relevant part of the documentation.